# Complete the task after user logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

When user is logged he can bookmark property, if not modal for login will appear. My problem is how can i remeber what he choose so when he logged in to bookmark that property that he clicked before he was logged in. Any suggestions?

```
  @if(Sentinel::check())
     @if($bookmark = in_array($property->id, $bookmarks))
     <a href="{{ route('public.property.unbookmark',$property->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
     @else
     <a href="{{ route('public.property.bookmark',$property->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
     @endif
     @else
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
     @endif
```

Comment: @Xorifelse it's a [Blade template engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) syntax.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin edited and added blade to the tags. It would had refrain me of making such a comment as I'm not familiar with laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is not logged, you can put values he bookmarked into php cookie. After loggin you can read the cookie values and retrieve data.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php